# UnsupportedEncodingException Error, but I'm not reading any files?

Tags: java, exception, hash, io

I'm working on an assignment to build a blockchain, and I have the following class called Block. Line 26, where I try to calculate the hash gives me the following error:

Error: unreported exception `java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException` must be caught or declared to be thrown

I am reading files in another class, but I did not have this problem in that file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

```
import java.util.Date; 
import java.sql.Timestamp; 
import java.io.*; 

public class Block { 

  private int index; //index of the block in the list
  public String hash; //the hash of the object 
  public String previousHash; //the hash of the previous object in the blockchain
  private java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp; //time at which the transaction has been process
  private Transaction transaction;  //the transaction object 
  private String nonce; //the random string for proof of work

  public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
  //  System.out.println(timeStamp.getTIme()); 
  } //closes main method

  //Block constructor 
  public Block(String data, String previousHash) { 
    this.previousHash = previousHash; 
    this.timeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
  } //closes constructor

  //calculating hash
  public String calculateHash() { 
    String calculatedHash = Sha1.hash(previousHash); 
    return calculatedHash; 
  } //closes calculateHash method

} //closes class
```

Answer (score 0):

That means you have to surround your Sha1.hash() call with a try / catch block that catches the UnsupportedEncodingException, or add it to the throws clause.

In Java there are checked and unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions are thrown in the runtime with no prior warning. Checked exceptions are a way of the api or function to warn you that an exception might occur and that you should handle it at compile time. That’s the case with your exception.

To check out more about the exceptions in Java refer to  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

You can also find an explanation on checked / unchecked exceptions here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/

Comment: I see, thank you! Do you know what causes that exception to occur?

Comment: It actually hasn’t occurred yet... I’ve updated the answer with clarification on that, feel free to ask if you still have any doubts. If it solved your problem, I’d thank you if you could accept it as the right answer. Happy coding!

Comment: As for what actually triggers the exception I’d have to take a look at Sha1.hash code, but I looked online and couldn’t find it. Is it an open source lib?